# iOS Parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON data in iOS. So far, I'm able to get the "name" part. How do I drill down to get the "coordinates"? I've tried

```
NSString *loc = [[[myArrayElement  objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
```

But I'm getting error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
 -(void) loadData
{
NSString *url =     @"https://sp.hsbc.com.my/api/offers/5549dbd92d9d88c161f51894/addresses";

NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^
               {
                   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
                   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
               });
}


- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
NSError* error;
NSArray *tArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

int i;
NSLog(@"start");
for (i = 0; i < [tArray count]; i++) {
    id myArrayElement = [tArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * result = [myArrayElement valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
NSLog(@"finish");
}
```

Comment: Show the full error.

Comment: Show what the JSON looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the Coordinates array as follows:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSArray *tArr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSArray *coordinates = NULL;
    NSString *name = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < [tArr count]; i++) {
        name = [[tArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        coordinates = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[tArr objectAtIndex:i]
                                               valueForKeyPath:@"loc.coordinates"]];

        NSLog(@"name : %@", name);
        NSLog(@"Coordinate 1 : %f Coordinate 2 : %f", [[coordinates objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue], [[coordinates objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]);
    }
}
```

**Essential Code:**

**valueForKeyPath** method of the Object and gave it the Coordinates Path as "loc.coordinates" so it must give me back an Array, which contains the two coordinates.

**And the result was as follows:**

```
2015-05-13 00:45:21.738 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot No. LG-24 & LG-75, Postal Address LG-50 & LG-75, Lower Ground Floor, Berjaya Times Square, No. 1, Jalan Imbi, 55100 Kuala Lumpur
2015-05-13 00:45:21.738 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.143915 Coordinate 2 : 101.712754
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot G13A, Ground Floor, AEON Bukit Indah Shopping Centre, No. 8, Jalan Indah 15/2, Bukit Indah, 81200 Johor Bahru
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 1.481790 Coordinate 2 : 103.655134
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] name : LG-94 & 96, Lower Ground Floor, IOI City Mall, Lebuh IRC, IOI Resort City, 62502 Putrajaya, Sepang Selangor
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 2.967136 Coordinate 2 : 101.709676
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] name : 170-G-66 & A1, Plaza Gurney, Persiaran Gurney, 10250 Penang
2015-05-13 00:45:21.739 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 5.434453 Coordinate 2 : 100.314887
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Cititel Hotel, Main Lobby, Ground Floor, Mid Valley city, Lingkaran Syed Putra, 59200 Kuala Lumpur
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.118272 Coordinate 2 : 101.678547
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] name : G-066, G-067, Dataran Pahlawan Melaka Megamall, Jalan Merdeka, Bandar Hilir, 75000 Melaka
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 2.190907 Coordinate 2 : 102.246098
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] name : G1.43, Ground Floor, Sunway Pyramid, No. 3 , Jln PJS 11/15, 46150 Petaling Jaya
2015-05-13 00:45:21.740 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.077040 Coordinate 2 : 101.604545
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] name : G63, Ground Floor, Aeon Ipoh Station 18 Shopping Centre, No. 2, Susuran Stesen 18, Station 18, 31650 Ipoh
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 4.543248 Coordinate 2 : 101.068835
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot 136 & 137,1st floor, The Curve, No.6 , Jalan PJU 7/3, Mutiara Damansara, 47820 Petaling Jaya, Selangor
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.157856 Coordinate 2 : 101.611218
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot G22 & 22A, Ground Floor, Cheras Leisure Mall, Taman Segar Cheras, 56100 KL 
2015-05-13 00:45:21.741 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.089950 Coordinate 2 : 101.741770
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot No 1.17, Storey No Level 1, Pavilion KL, 168, Jalan Bukit Bintang, 50200 Kuala Lumpur
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.148658 Coordinate 2 : 101.713065
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot S313A, 2nd Floor Highstreet, 1 Utama Shopping Mall, No. 1 Lebuh Bandar Utama, 47800 Petaling Jaya
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.136550 Coordinate 2 : 101.608334
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot no 1.17, storey no Level 1, Pavilion KL, 168, Jalan Bukit Bintang, 50200 Kuala Lumpur 
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.149111 Coordinate 2 : 101.713500
2015-05-13 00:45:21.742 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot no J3-36, Level 3, Johor Bahru City Square, 106-108, Jalan Wong Ah Fook, 80000 Johor Bahru 
2015-05-13 00:45:21.743 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 1.461514 Coordinate 2 : 103.763848
2015-05-13 00:45:21.743 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Lot no. G53, AEON Bukit Tinggi Shopping Centre, No. 1 Persiaran Batu Nikam 1/KS 6, Bandar Bukit Tinggi 2, 41200 Klang 
2015-05-13 00:45:21.743 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 2.997926 Coordinate 2 : 101.437115
2015-05-13 00:45:21.743 TestApp[5788:35074] name : Unit # UG-18, Setia City Mall, UG-18No. 7, Persiaran Setia Dagang, Bandar Setia Alam Seksyen U13, Selangor, 40170 Shah Alam,
2015-05-13 00:45:21.743 TestApp[5788:35074] Coordinate 1 : 3.104556 Coordinate 2 : 101.490712
```

Hope this would be helpful to you!

Comment: Thanks. Both your code and explanation was very helpful.

Comment: I was in search for a good Application of JSON Decode in iOS using Obj-C.
Hope it would be helpful to you in the following tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based

Try it out whenever you have some free time!

Answer (score 1):

Change the for loop to the following

```
for (i = 0; i < [tArray count]; i++) {
    id myArrayElement = [tArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * result = [myArrayElement valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [myArrayElement valueForKey:@"loc"];
    NSArray *coordArray = [loc valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
    NSString *lat = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *long = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Comment: You should not use KVC's `-valueForKey:` to access a dictionary's values.

Comment: Because that's not how dictionaries work. Use -objectForKey:.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html)! instead of iterate over the array.

```
NSArray *tArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [tArray objectAtIndex: 0];
NSArray *loc = [myDictionary allKeysForObject: @"coordinates"];
```

Then:

```
NSString *lat = [loc objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *long = [loc objectAtIndex:1];
```